# iOS 14 & XCode 12 beta 2 - Reading data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I'm coding an iOS app with XCode 12 beta 2, and I'm stuck because I need to read some data from Firebase.
I took the code by default from Firebase documentation and added some stuff :

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        
    print("Logged in!")
    
    // Loading Database
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    ref = Database.database().reference()
        
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
    ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
        // Get user values
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let dataFirstname = value?["firstname"] as? String ?? ""
        let dataLastname = value?["lastname"] as? String ?? ""
            
        // Setup labels
        self.namesLabel.text = "\(dataFirstname) \(dataLastname)"
        self.passwordLabel.text = self.password
        self.emailLabel.text = self.email
            
      }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

The problem is that "dataFirstname" and "dataLastname" aren't get from the database. The problem seems to come from the line "let value = ....." from what I saw when debugging the code.
I'm still new at Swift so, any help would be appreciated!
Thanks for reading, and I hope you'll help me!
-- Max.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `nil` if `snapshot.value` is not representable as an NSDictionary (which is kind of deprecated in Swift).

The quickest way to see the correct type is to log the object :
`print(snapshot.value)`

You can also add a breakpoint and inspect the content

Comment: I did "print(snapshot.value)" and it printed "Optional(<null>)"

Comment: Are you sure that the User `UserId` really exists ?

Comment: yes, I added breakpoints and UserId is replaced by the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I've succeeded to correctly read the data. For those who are interrested in it, here's my final code. Thanks to all the people who helped me!

```
// Loggin-in
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        
    if error != nil {
            
        // Couldn't log-in
        self.alertUser("Error", error!.localizedDescription)
            
    } else {
            
        print("Logged in!")
        
        // Loading Database
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let ref = db.collection("users").document(userID!)

        ref.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                    
                var dataDescription = document.data()
                print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
                    
                // Get values from data
                self.FirstName = dataDescription?.removeValue(forKey: "firstname") as! String
                self.LastName = dataDescription?.removeValue(forKey: "lastname") as! String
                    
                // Setup labels
                self.namesLabel.text = "\(self.FirstName) \(self.LastName)"
                self.passwordLabel.text = self.password
                self.emailLabel.text = self.email
                    
            } else {
                    
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
    }
}
```